# Simple Design and Diagram Software: Need recommendations

Tags: diagram

I need half-art-half-engineering software to draw diagrams of the design concepts (mostly 2D). I need something that let me type the coordinates, can toggle snapping the mouse to the grid like AutoCAD, and edit the colors and line widths as well as bucket-fill a space like Photoshop. So this software can replace my colored pencils and rulers to liberate me from the stone age. Vector diagram is preferred though not a must. Any suggestions from my awesome community?

Comment: Even though your post is not clear, I would definitely suggest Inkscape.

Comment: Everything you describe is possible using almost any vector software - the typing in of co-ordinates is possible, but not really an optimal way to do graphic design. Also you don't need to use a bucket fill for vectors. You only have to change the fill or stroke attributes of an object. Software such as Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape (which is free), or CorelDraw etc.  These aren't meant for engineering though. They are graphic design software. If you need absolute accuracy use CAD software, but CAD or Engineering is off-topic here.

Comment: Probably better suited to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you can make tasteful and finished looking drawings with trad tools do NOT scrap it! Many of us have never developed that skill to perfection and depend on software to be able to output anything polished looking. Unfortunately the limitations of the programs work like a fetter when one lets his imagination fly.